# Construct algebraic expression equivalent to trig function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I make an algebraic expression that is equivalent to this type of trig function:

**cos(arcsin x)**

The answer is: **sqr(1 - x^2)**

No clue how to get there. Teacher didn't explain very well.

Comment: Hint: draw a right-angled triangle and use the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2x =1$, then we know that $\cos^2x = 1 - \sin^2x$. Accordingly, set $\sin(\arcsin(x))=x$, then use the identity for $\cos^2 x$ to get
$$\cos(\arcsin(x))^2=1-\sin(\arcsin(x))^2$$
$$\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-\sin(\arcsin(x))^2}$$
$$\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$